# Django admin save_model not advancing primary key in Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

So I have a function in the Django admin that allows me to create a duplicate `MyModel` in the database:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if '_saveasnew' in request.POST:
        old_obj_id = resolve(request.path).args[0]
        old_obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=old_obj_id)
        obj.other_id = old_obj.other_id
        obj.status = old_obj.status
        obj.project_id = old_obj.project_id
        obj.test_url = old_obj.test_url
        obj.save()
    super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

This creation works fine, but I have another system interacting with this database that is seeing insert failures every time this function has been called. For example, if I create 2 duplicate entries in the Django admin this way, then the other system will see two errors like

> IntegrityError duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_model_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1234) already exists.

I'm using Django 1.11.15 & PostgreSQL 9.5.15.

Comment: What version of Django are you running? Note that Django drops support for old PostgreSQL versions as the version number is increased. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#dropped-support-for-postgresql-9-3 or any other related version.

Comment: @GjertG Added versions used.

Comment: Are both applications using the same version? I'm assuming "Another system" refers to a separate Django application? My guess is that there is a problem with regards to pointing to the correct objects.

Comment: What exactly are the arguments passed into the function? Most curious about the obj argument.

Comment: The "other system" in this example is just direct SQL insert statements. And the `save_model` function is an overridden one in the Django ModelAdmin class ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model))

Comment: And which system is seeing errors? It could be the super() which is calling the superiour of both applications, though there not enough code to debug from my part as your code looks fine. It all depends on the rest of your code tbh.

Comment: The code above is not auto-incrementing the primary key in the database for some reason. The other application doesn't matter. I can query the database directly (e.g. `SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_model', 'id'))`) and see the the primary key hasn't been incremented.

Comment: Auto-incrementing the primary key in the database should not be up to Django. This should automatically be done by the database engine upon creating new rows. However, by looking at your code there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. So its hard for me to tell what is occurring without any more information. However, try wrapping the entire super condition with a transaction.atomic and see what happens. Could be a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that somewhere your code is telling your database to create a new object row and explicitly set the ID of that row to be X. When really the code should be telling your database to create a new object row and implicitly set the ID of that row to be whatever the next available integer is.

Your code is confusing because you're doing it in a very complicated way. Why does this function take in both an object and a request? And then it finds the old object from the request? Where was the new object created?

A simpler way would be to first check if you want to save as new. If not, have a function that updates an object and give it the existing object. If it is a Save As New Request, create a new object row that has similar the values as the existing object (except ID). And then update that new object with the changes. Or however your logic should work. In any case, there is a much more straightforward way of accomplishing the steps that you want to happen if you think about how the steps are ordered.

Comment: Could you write rather than describe the code for your "simpler way"?